# Android App Communicating with USB CDC Device

Tags: android

I am Developing Android  App That Receive Data From USB CDC Device.
Thinking that my android phone is host. The Device should get power from the android phone only. The cable Used for Data Transfer and power is Same.

But here Data Not Receiving from USB CDC Device to Mobile.

Here is code snippet from what I have tried

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbConstants;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbDeviceConnection;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbInterface;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
    import android.hardware.usb.UsbRequest;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
    import java.nio.CharBuffer;
    import java.nio.CharBuffer;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        boolean Run= true;
        boolean Communication_Ok;
        Button btn;
        UsbManager manager;
        UsbDevice device;
        UsbDeviceConnection connection;
        UsbInterface Inf;
        UsbEndpoint  Data_In_End_Point =null;
        UsbEndpoint  Data_Out_End_Point =null;
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(255);
        UsbRequest request = new UsbRequest();

        static  int s1,s2,s3;


    TextView tv1;
        PendingIntent mPermissionIntent;
        private static final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
            tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            check_devices();
           btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   call_next_Intent();
                    if (!Receive.isAlive())
                        Receive.start();


                    }
            });

        }

        private void call_next_Intent() {
            Intent Home=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Home.class);
            startActivity(Home);
        }

        private void check_devices()
        {
            manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
            mPermissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION);
            registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
            HashMap<String , UsbDevice> deviceList = manager.getDeviceList();
            Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
            String returnValue = "";
            while (deviceIterator.hasNext()) {
                device = deviceIterator.next();
                manager.requestPermission(device, mPermissionIntent);

                returnValue += "Name: " + device.getDeviceName();
                returnValue += "\nID: " + device.getDeviceId();
                returnValue += "\nProtocol: " + device.getDeviceProtocol();
                returnValue += "\nClass: " + device.getDeviceClass();
                returnValue += "\nSubclass: " + device.getDeviceSubclass();
                returnValue += "\nProduct ID: " + device.getProductId();
                returnValue += "\nVendor ID: " + device.getVendorId();
                returnValue += "\nInterface count: " + device.getInterfaceCount();

                for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
                    Inf = device.getInterface(i);
                    returnValue += "\n  Interface " + i;
                    returnValue += "\n\tInterface ID: " + Inf.getId();
                    returnValue += "\n\tClass: " + Inf.getInterfaceClass();
                    returnValue += "\n\tProtocol: " + Inf.getInterfaceProtocol();
                    returnValue += "\n\tSubclass: " + Inf.getInterfaceSubclass();
                    returnValue += "\n\tEndpoint count: " + Inf.getEndpointCount();

                    for (int j = 0; j < Inf.getEndpointCount(); j++) {
                        returnValue += "\n\t  Endpoint " + j;
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tAddress: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getAddress();
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tAttributes: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getAttributes();
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tDirection: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getDirection();
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tNumber: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getEndpointNumber();
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tInterval: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getInterval();
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tType: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getType();
                        returnValue += "\n\t\tMax packet size: " + Inf.getEndpoint(j).getMaxPacketSize();
                    }
                }

            }

                tv1.setText(returnValue);
        }
        private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
        {

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action))
                {
                    synchronized (this)
                    {
                       device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false))
                        {
                            if(device != null)
                            {
                                connection = manager.openDevice(device);

                                if (!connection.claimInterface(device.getInterface(0), true))
                                {
                                    return;
                                }

                                connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
                                connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 1, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Rx
                                connection.controlTransfer(0x21, 0x22, 0x1, 0, null, 0, 0);//DTR signal
                                connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx

                                connection.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03,0x001A, 0, null, 0, 0);//For baudrate

                                 Inf = device.getInterface(0);
                                for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
                                    // communications device class (CDC) type device
                                    if (device.getInterface(i).getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_CDC_DATA) {
                                        Inf = device.getInterface(i);

                                        // find the endpoints
                                        for (int j = 0; j < Inf.getEndpointCount(); j++) {
                                            if (Inf.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_OUT && Inf.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                                                // from android to device
                                                Data_Out_End_Point = Inf.getEndpoint(j);
                                            }

                                            if (Inf.getEndpoint(j).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN && Inf.getEndpoint(j).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                                                // from device to android
                                                Data_In_End_Point = Inf.getEndpoint(j);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }


                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.d("ERROR", "permission denied for device " + device);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
     public Thread Receive  = new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                byte[] Recieved_Data;
                int i;
                buffer.clear();
                while (Run){
                    request.initialize(connection, Data_In_End_Point);

                    request.queue(buffer,255);
                    if (connection.requestWait() !=null)
                    {

                            Recieved_Data=buffer.array();
                            if (Recieved_Data[0]==0x02 && Recieved_Data[2]==0x03){
                                if (Recieved_Data[1]==0x11){
                                    s1++;
                                }
                                else if (Recieved_Data[1]==0x22){
                                    s2++;
                                }
                                else if (Recieved_Data[1]==0x33){
                                    s3++;

                                }
                            }


                    }

                }

                }

        });


    }
```

Comment: Do not copy the same text twice - it's a spam. Also, reduce amount of code to only show part where your problem is. And format it properly.

Comment: Is your device showing up when you enumerate the endpoints?  Also, you can't just plugin a device like a mouse to an Android tablet unless it has a host port.  You would need an OTG cable. I'd suggest getting the app USB Device Info and see if the device is even showing  up.  https://f-droid.org/packages/aws.apps.usbDeviceEnumerator/

Comment: yes when i Enumerate the interfaces and endpoints my Application is showing correct details .But When Connected Device is Sending Data My android App Does Not getting ........Is Any solution for This.Can you Just Explain In Brief.....